# Vue js - display an element from a list based on the current time

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, vue-component

Im receiving an objects (trips) list from an API and i want to check if theres any trip object thats satisfy below logic :

trip object consists of -> startTime, estimatedTime, begin, destination

logic : if theres a trip that satisfies `startTime + estimatedTime < currentTime` so, display the component.

Currently all the trips that in the list is being shown :

```
    <div class="col-xs-24">
        <Loading :data="passengerTrips" :hideOnEmpty="true">
            <h2 slot="title" > Trips which im going</h2>
            <div class="trips-list">
                <Trip v-for="trip in passengerTrips" :trip="trip" :user="user"></Trip>
            </div>
        </Loading>
    </div>

<script>
    watch: {
    passengerTrips: function () {
        this.updateScroll();
    },
    computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        passengerTrips: 'myTrips/passengerTrips'
    }),
</script>
```

I'm a newbie to vue so any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't recommend using `v-if` inside `for` loop but I guess you can filter your trips inside your store.

Answer (score 0):

startTime, estimatedTime, begin, destination

You can have a getter in your store:

```
getters: {
  ...,
  tripsOnTime: state => {
    const currentTime = new Date(); // Format the time based on your requirements
    // return only the trips that meet the condition
    // Validation to check if trip is not undefined/null
    return state.trips.filter(trip => trip && trip.startTime + trip.estimatedTime < currentTime
  },
  ...
}
```

Now you can add it:

```
<script>
  watch: {
    passengerTrips: function () {
      this.updateScroll();
    },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
    passengerTrips: 'myTrips/passengerTrips',
    tripsOnTime: 'myTrips/tripsOnTime',    
  }),
</script>
```

I added `trip` to the validation:

```
return state.trips.filter(trip => trip && trip.startTime + trip.estimatedTime < currentTime
```

If you want to check each property, then you can do it with the `&&` operator, with hasOwnProperty method for objects.

Comment: what if trip has ``null` value?

Comment: You can validate that trap or its properties are not null, I added the code to check that trip is not null to my answer, but you can add validations to know that each property is not null.